# Change fragment on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

I have to implement an application in which the user can click through a bottom_bar between 5 pages (although google does not recommend it in recent documents, the customer is always right).
So I created a swipe activity with automatic tool android study.
Question: how do I start the transation, after the click on the button, and change fragment??

Here is the code (at the time the activity change with the swipe)

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ImageView home, ospitalita,multimedia,territoro, prodotti;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibHome);
        ospitalita = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibOspitalita);
        multimedia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibMultimedia);
        territoro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibTerritorio);
        prodotti = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibProdotti);

       mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        View.OnClickListener gestore = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


//this is the bottom bar, on click, change icon color

               switch (v.getId()){
                   case R.id.ibHome:
                       changeBottomIcon("home");
                       mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);  //do nothing
                        break;

                   case R.id.ibOspitalita:
                       changeBottomIcon("ospitalita");
                       mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
                       break;

                   case R.id.ibMultimedia:
                       changeBottomIcon("multimedia");
                       mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
                       break;

                   case R.id.ibTerritorio:
                       changeBottomIcon("territorio");
                       mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(3);
                       break;

                   case R.id.ibProdotti:
                       changeBottomIcon("prodotti");
                       mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(4);
                       break;

                }
            }
        };

        home.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        ospitalita.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        multimedia.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        territoro.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        prodotti.setOnClickListener(gestore);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

            switch (position) {

// change bottom doesn't work here
                case 0:
                   // changeBottomIcon("home");  
                    return new fragment_home();
                case 1:
                    //changeBottomIcon("territorio");
                    return new fragment_territorio();
                case 2:
                  //changeBottomIcon("ospitalita");
                    return new fragment_ospitalita();
                case 3:
                //changeBottomIcon("multimedia");
                    return new fragment_multimedia();
                case 4:
                  //changeBottomIcon("prodotti");
                    return new fragment_prodotti();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
           //num pagine
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            //Not visible, no nav bar
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.home);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.territorio);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.ospitalita);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.multimedia);
                case 4:
                    return getString(R.string.prodotti);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

//simple method to change icon color
    public void changeBottomIcon(String tipo){
      .
      .
      .
//lo ometto perchè inutile

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

(see the [android dev docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)) for further information)

Comment: so simple?
I went crazy for something stupid.
Arrive at the office and I try

Comment: While this may be the answer, it is recommended to include documentation and/or explanation in your answer.